# Broken Images on Django

Tags: python, html, django, imagefield

I am getting broken images on django. Below are the relevant information with code, I guess. I am new to django and any information would be greatly appreciated.

name of project/site=imagesite
name of app=gallery

in models.py,

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    pub_date = timezone.now()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

in views.py,

```
def view_gallery(request):
    photo_list = Photo.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'gallery/view_gallery.html', {'photo_list' : photo_list})
```

in view_gallery.html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for photo in photo_list.all %}

        <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" width="240">
        <h2> {{ photo.pub_date }} </h2>
        <br>

    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

in settings.py,

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'imagesite/media')
```

in imagesite/urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('imagesite/', include('gallery.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

in gallery/urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.view_gallery, name='view_gallery'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Tip for debugging this kind of issue: Always look in your browser for the HTML source code and see what the "src" attribute of your <img> is. You'll see that "/media/" is missing as prefix.

Comment: `{{ photo.image.url }}` isn't the correct url to your image, it needs to be prefixed with the `MEDIA_URL`. Use `{% get_media_prefix %}{{ photo.image.url }}` instead.

Comment: @dirkgroten I tried it once but it raised a TemplateSyntaxError because I hadn't put {%load static%} (I guess). Then I fixed it and am still getting a broken image. (I appreciate the tip)

Comment: correct, you need to `load static` first. It should work. Again: look at the url in your browser (and tell us what it is in your question). Also look at your file system and check the image is inside __<projectfolder>/imagesite/media/images/<yourimagehere>.png__. This should map to the url _/media/images/<yourimagehere>.png_

Comment: Does it have to be a png? Or can it be any type of image file? Yes, my image is in such a hierarchy.

Comment: Any image. Please tell us what is the src attribute in your HTML that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `static()` urls should be added to the main urls.py file, not to your `gallery/urls.py`. Now you're prepending them with `/imagesite/` so basically you're telling django to create urls `/imagesite/media/` rather than `/media/`.

Also, just for clarity: This is a url setting that should **only be used for development**, not for production. So it's better to do like this in your main urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('imagesite/', include(gallery.urls)),
    ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Finally, don't assume '/' for paths, as you see you're on Windows, so the path separator is a '\'. Your `MEDIA_ROOT` setting creates a folder "imagesite/media" rather than a folder "media" inside a folder "imagesite":

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'imagesite', 'media')
```